# Will the site association bonus come after I already have the account?

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-accounts, association-bonus, association

I have an account with close to 100 reputation on *[Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

-

When I get 200 reputation, will the site association bonus apply to already existing accounts (like my meta.se - this account),

or

- Does it only apply to new communities joined thereafter?

And if I do get it on previous accounts, will I get +100 rep or enough to make my balance 100?

Comment: +100 on all sites.